# How to handle the (windows)open button while uploading the file in seleniumwebdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

While uploading the file using selenium web driver its working upto setting the file path.The open is not working while running the code.

```
        db.findElement(By.id("button-upload222")).click();
        Robot robo = new Robot();
        StringSelection str = new StringSelection(myLoginData1[2][c]);



  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(str,null);
        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        db.findElement(By.id("Open")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Alert alert = db.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
```

excepted: successfully uploaded prompt
actual result: file is not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use sendkeys instead of using robot class.
Locate the attachment button till input tag and use locatedElement.sendKeys(filePath)